# How to Set Header Text of Modal Dialog According to the Table element and his ID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hello everyone and sorry in advance for my very bad English.

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project with a JavaScript framework as the front-end.

I have a table which contains customer names retrieved from a database. Now I want to show a modal dialog and set the text of its header according to the customer name which has been clicked. At the same time I would like to get the customer Id. For example, when clicking "Georges", the modal dialog pops up and its header text is set to "Georges".

Here is my code.

The customer table look like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="DailyTask">
    <h4>Daily Tasks</h4>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
      List<SchedulerTool.Models.spGetDailyBatchTask_Result> batches = Model.DailyTask;

      foreach (var batch in batches)
      {
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning" id="dailybatch">
          <input name="currentdailyBatchId" id="@batch.BatchId" hidden type="text" value="@batch.BatchId" />
          <input name="currentdailyBatchName" id=" @batch.BatchName " hidden type="text" value=@batch.BatchName />
          <button class="btn btn-group-justified" id="dailybatchTask" data-title="@batch.BatchName" data-target="#dailybatchTaskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-bid="@batch.BatchId"> 
            <span class="fa-bitbucket-square" id="name">@batch.BatchName</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      }
    }
  </div>
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
$('dailybatchTask').on('click', function ()
{    
    var  batchId = $(this).data('bid');
    var batchName = $(this).data('title');

    // Here I set the table name a template table                        
    $("h4 a#bathDailyTaskModalLabel").html(batchName);

    // Here I set the Id to a template table                                   
    loadMasterTable("LoadObjectsNotBatched", batchId, DailyBatchElementUrl, "DailyBatchCollapseElementId");
});
```

Customers table:
[image: customers table]

The modal that is popover when clicked on customer:
[image: the modal that is popover when clicked on customer]

The problem is: when I clicked on the first element of the customer table, the modal is correctly shown (the header and id are correct) but when I clicked on the others elements the JavaScript code is not executed.

Hope someone can try to understand my problem and will help me!

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Change to using class instead and should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch all buttons by ids. But in HTML ids must be unique. Because that jquery your click event only matches first data. You need to fix ids before jquery part. If you really need it you can define a counter for loop and use it like this;

> id="dailybatchTask-@counter"

But you already defined data-bid so basically, you can just add a class name for the button like this;

> class="btn btn-group-justified daily-batch-button"

then only you need to;

```
$('daily-batch-button').on('click', function () {
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: waww , thank you so much @Ozan Alpkaya . everythings works now thanks to your smart answer !! Good bless you §

Comment: Hello everyone,